# WPF item panel that keeps aspect ratio

Tags: wpf, layout, panel, aspect-ratio

I have an ItemsControl which may contain an arbitrary number of items (unknown at design time).  Each of these items is basically represented as an infinitely-scalable image with a fixed aspect ratio (ie. the image will draw itself in whatever space is given to it -- it does not dictate its own size except that the aspect ratio must be preserved).  The aspect ratio for each item *might* differ but is usually the same.

I want to:

- Draw a border around each image, ideally of uniform thickness regardless of image scaling.
- Draw each image as large as possible within the window, while maintaining its order, aspect ratio, and margins external to the border.
- At least two of the four sides of an image must always touch the invisible boundaries of the cell it is within.  The other two sides should be centred if not touching.  (Assuming that some sort of uniform cell layout is used.)
- Not overlap or clip any images.
- Automatically re-layout as the containing window is resized.
- Waste the minimum amount of non-image space.
- Cope as well as possible if the aspect ratios of the items differ.  (But it's ok if this increases the wasted space of other items, as long as they rescale to fit the result.)

The general consensus that I've found seems to be to wrap each image in a Stretch.Uniform Viewbox, and then put those into a UniformGrid.  I've tried that approach but it doesn't appeal to me because:

- Given two items, the UniformGrid always wants to create a 2x2 grid layout even when the window shape would make a 2x1 or 1x2 grid more suitable, which results in over-scaling and wasted space.
- If I put the Border within the Viewbox then it scales the border thickness.  If I put it outside then it distorts the aspect ratio.

Is there a better way to do this?  (Note that the "image" is actually my own custom-draw FrameworkElement, so I can put custom measure/arrange code in here or in a custom container panel if it will help.)

---

```
<UniformGrid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Margin="4" Width="500" Height="281.25" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="4" Width="500" Height="281.25" />
</UniformGrid>
```

Here's a simple example.  Put this into a window, then try resizing the window.  The rectangles change size to fit the window (good), but they also change shape/aspect (bad), and they stop resizing once the window is sufficiently large (bad).  Also it leaves space for an entire 2x2 grid even when the window itself is sized such that 1x2 or 2x1 would work better.

```
<UniformGrid>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Margin="4"><Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="500" Height="281.25" /></Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Margin="4"><Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="500" Height="281.25" /></Viewbox>
</UniformGrid>
```

This works marginally better in that the rectangles continue to stretch when the window gets large, and they no longer distort their shape, but there's still the needless second row when the window is wide or second column when the window is narrow.  And I would prefer that the elements line up from the top left (like a WrapPanel) rather than centering, but that's a minor detail.

(And now try adding a Border, both inside and outside of the Viewbox, and see what I mean there.)

Actually a WrapPanel almost does what I want, except that it auto-sizes the items too large when the window gets smaller.

Comment: Given such a complex scenario, a screenshot and some revelant XAML would really help.

Comment: It's not all that complex to describe, I thought.  And I don't have any XAML, it's all done in code.  But if nobody responds for a while I might see if I can make some mockups.

Comment: `it's all done in code` - Ah, sorry, I though you were speaking about WPF, not some random dinosaur UI framework where you do everything in procedural code.

Comment: I know what you mean, but sadly in this case it's required.  The content elements use a third party control that breaks the designer if you try to use it from XAML (and can't even be added to the window until after its Load event).  I could probably make a mockup that uses mostly XAML though.

Comment: designer? I don't know what that means (ironic)

Comment: Yeah, I tend to hand-write my XAML too.  But it's still nicer if the designer works, so you can at least see how it looks before actually running the app.

Comment: ok, time to go home. Post some screenshots and let me know, so I can get a better picture of what you're after.

Comment: I added some sample XAML; though like I said in reality I'm using something more complicated than a Rectangle.

Comment: Ok, I think I've found a working solution now.